# BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui can't build because filepaths too long

Tags: c#, maui, google-vision

I've added the `BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui` package to my MAUI app and I'm getting these file copying errors while building it (an example below). The paths are clearly too long. If I move the solution to my root disk folder it starts to build but this is not a viable solution for me as need the solution to be in my git repository subfolder and unfortunately, it doesn't build there.

Is there any other solution to this problem?

> Error MSB3021 Unable to copy file
> "C:\Users\UserX.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\PrivateHeaders\GULCCComponentContainerInternal.h"
> to
> "bin\Debug\net8.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\PrivateHeaders\GULCCComponentContainerInternal.h".
> Could not find a part of the path
> 'bin\Debug\net8.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\PrivateHeaders\GULCCComponentContainerInternal.h'.

The post to which mine got associated with does not answer my question. The answer to it only says that the problem is that paths are too long which I already know and even point it out in the title and I'm asking about the actual SOLUTION to this problem. Hence my question is NOT a duplicate!